# How to use windows-sys to set a global hook for mouse click

Tags: winapi, rust

I am a beginner in rust

Now i'm using windows-sys to set a hook for mouse click

windows-sys provide a function named SetWindowsHookA like this

```
#[doc = "*Required features: `\"Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging\"`, `\"Win32_Foundation\"`*"]
    #[cfg(feature = "Win32_Foundation")]
    pub fn SetWindowsHookA(nfiltertype: i32, pfnfilterproc: HOOKPROC) -> HHOOK;
```

I found in the documentation that i can use this method to set a hook

But this function takes a HOOKPROC parameter

I don't know how do I get such a parameter

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about [SetWindowsHookExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa). And it's corresponding [windows-sys documentation](https://docs.rs/windows-sys/latest/windows_sys/Win32/UI/WindowsAndMessaging/fn.SetWindowsHookExA.html).

```rust
use windows_sys::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::{SetWindowsHookExA, UnhookWindowsHookEx};

const WH_MOUSE: i32 = 7;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let hook_id =
            SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE, Some(hook_callback), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Where `HOOKPROC` parameter looks like:

```
extern "system" fn hook_callback(code: i32, wparam: usize, lparam: isize) -> isize {
    0
}
```

Also remember to unhook using `UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook_id);` when you are done. Other than this the code should look similar to any C/C++ tutorial around hooking.

Comment: Capturing mouse and keyboard: https://github.com/SubconsciousCompute/KMI